# Renaming file via UNC path

Tags: vb.net, networking, rename

I need to have my VB.NET program rename a file over the network.

Microsoft says that `My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile` does not work if the file path starts with two backslashes (`"\\"`).  So, what other way is there of doing this?  I just need to rename a file in the domain, for instance:

```
rename("\\domain\1\exemple.txt", "\\domain\1\exemple2.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for rename should be just the file name eg:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\Test.txt", "SecondTest.txt")
```

So try changing your code to this:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(@"\\domain\1\exemple.txt", "exemple2.txt")
```

Also beware of escaping because `\` is an escape character, so add a `@` before any string that contains `\`. This will cause it to ignore escaping and therefore will treat `\` as a normal character

Comment: The rename() was just an example of code (not in a real programing language).

I think im just confused xD. 
I went here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w05844e.aspx
It said:
"
The path is not valid for one of the following reasons: it is a zero-length string, it contains only white space, it contains invalid characters, or it is a device path (starts with \\.\)"

So i assumed it didnt work with "\\" then i saw "\\. \" and because im not on a network i cant test it. So i posted my question in anticipation. Sorry my bad oO

Comment: @lemario Ok, see my edit. add a `@` before the first parameter string.

Comment: Hmm you are talking about adding '@' in the forum not the code right? xD

Comment: `@` is C#, not VB.NET.  The backslash character is not an escape character in VB.NET and is therefore totally safe.

Comment: Ok you were talking about the code. Im noob sorry oO And thanks @StevenDoggart